# NTFS rw-support for Mac via fstab not working

Tags: mac, ntfs, fstab

I have used an NTFS partition for a long time with my Mac getting rw support for it via the "LABEL=DriveName none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse" entry in /etc/fstab.

I reinstalled Yosemite last night just to refresh things and now the entry in fstab prevents the NTFS drive to mount.

After creating the fstab entry and rebooting the NTFS drive was nowhere to be found, I can see it as unmounted in disk util and when I try to mount it from there I get the error message "Mount Failed The disk could not be mounted."

removing the fstab line makes me able to mount the drive but without write support of course, what is going on? Any ideas on how to make this work again as it did before the reinstall?

Comment: What is the name ('label') of the drive? Make sure it doesn't contain any space. Your fstab line seems fine.

Comment: No spaces in the name, the drive name is Bulk. I have also tried to substitute the LABEL for UUID and using the drives UUID but no luck...

Comment: Does [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152661/ntfs-usb-drives-on-yosemite) help?